# Double integration using Nintegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

```
P0del[al_, x_] := 
  NIntegrate[
 E^(-  al a (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + a) - a) - 2 h (-1 + a) + a)), {a, 0, 
 x}]/NIntegrate[
  E^(- al a (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + a) - a) - 2 h (-1 + a) + a)), {a, 0, 
   1}];

 I1del[al_, x_?NumericQ] := 
   E^(- al x (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + x) - x) - 2 h (-1 + x) + x));
   A[al_, x_] := (NIntegrate[I1del[al, x1], {x1, 0, x}])/
    (NIntegrate[I1del[al, x1], {x1, 0, 1}]);

 firstt0[al_, x_?NumericQ] := 
   A[al, x]  NIntegrate[
   P0del[al, x1]/(
    x1 (1 - x1) E^(- 
    al x1 (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + x1) - x1) - 2 h (-1 + x1) + x1)))
    int2[al, x1], {x1, 0, 1}];
 int2[al_, x1_] /; NumericQ[x1] := 
  NIntegrate[
   E^(- al y (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + y) - y) - 2 h (-1 + y) + y)), {y, x1, 
   1}];


 secondt0[al_, x_?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[ 
   P0del[al, x1]/(x1 (1 - x1) I1del[al, x1])  (int23[al, x1]), {x1, 0,
    x}, MaxRecursion -> 20];
 int23[al_, x1_] /; NumericQ[x1] := 
   NIntegrate[
   E^(- al y (f (2 + 2 h (-1 + y) - y) - 2 h (-1 + y) + y)), {y, x1, 
   x}];

   t0del1[al_, x_] := firstt0[al, x] - secondt0[al, x];


     Clear[N1, f, h, al, th, p]

     th =  \[Pi]/4;
      N1 = 2000;
     f = 0.8;
      sig1=0.01;
      al = -N1 sig1 Sin[th]
       h = 0.81;
       p = 1/(2 N1);

       2 N1 ((t0del1[al, p])/P0del[al, p])
```

Please look at the above simple code. I need to make a function of x which is a double integration function such that if I plug the value of x in the end it gives me answer. when I try to do the same it does not give me result.

Comment: There is an undefined object; I1del

Comment: sir, please check the edited one, by mistake I forgot to copy I1del.

Comment: NIntegrate only works if integrand is numeric! For example looking at `P0del` there are several undefined parameters `f,h`

Comment: sir, but i specified all these parameters in the end before evaluating the quantity.

Comment: P0del is undefined. It is good practice to copy the code that is to be submitted and paste it into a new kernel to check if it is o.k.

Comment: `al` is a parameter(value `-14.1421`)   and used as a function argument, confusing and dangerous!

Comment: @ Daniel Huber sir in the first line P0del is defined. if I put x=p; it gives me value but I want to keep it as a function of x only.

Comment: @ ulrich Neumann i wanted to make the functions of argument al and x. in the end I pass the values of each of them. Could you please suggest any alternative way? I have to make t0del1 as a function of al and x for my purpose.